# cannot display French characters in html select options

Tags: jsp, web-applications

I have a jsp page "myAccount.jsp". It includes a header jsp using:

```
<%@ include file="jspHeader.jsp"%>
```

In jspHeader.jsp, charset is defined as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
```

In myAccount.jsp I have to hard code two strings: "English" and "français" in html select options:

```
<select name="Lang"> 
    <option value=""><fmt:message key="myaccount_lbl_13" bundle="${lang}"/></option>
    <option <%if (LangVal.equals("en")){%> selected <%}%> value="en">English</option>
    <option <%if (LangVal.equals("fr")){%> selected <%}%> value="fr">français</option>
</select>
```

The problem is in IE the French word "français" is displayed incorrectly. This is true if I added encoding in myAccount.jsp as

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Anybody knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The two declarations `charset=windows-1252` and `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` seem contradictory. Try to use UTF8 everywhere.

If it doesn't work, you can use `&ccedil;` to print a c cédille.